# Python logging strange behaviour when using a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

Something very strange is happening with the logging module and I do not really get what is going on.

I am setting the debugging level to NOTSET, so nothing should be printed to the stdout, so far this was working, however once I added the three following lines I start getting debug messages from info level.

```
#start get LOADS thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.getLoads,args=(5,))
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()

log.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

**EDIT:**

The thread is not even logging. However when I spawn the thread, the logging level from the main thread gets set to INFO, and I don't do anything.

Comment: I'd expect setting the log level before starting the code that can log stuff would make a difference, what if you do the `log.setLevel` first?

Comment: Second the comment above. You are copying the logging object into the new thread, but setting the level only of the version in the local thread.

Comment: The thread does not even have logs. The logging level in the main "thread" is what changes. I start getting all the `log.info()` from the main thread. I really don't get it.